# Android Issue with WebView and overriding the url

Tags: android, https, webview, redirect

Below is the code which we are using to load the WebView. Capturing the url and redirecting to a new activity page is done using the  “shouldOverrideUrlLoading”, once the user click on log in button in html page in the webview. But when loading the page, the page is redirecting after the security check(redirecting to https page) and control is coming to the “shouldOverrideUrlLoading” function and its making the activity blank. If we remove the  “shouldOverrideUrlLoading” function we can see the log in screen on the WebView. But we are not able to go to the new activity. I tried to catch the redirection url and load it on the
“shouldOverrideUrlLoading” function, but its not allowing to load the content. And I try to return true and false for different conditions form “shouldOverrideUrlLoading” function that also not working.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to load the log in page in the WebView after the redirecting from the security check and override the url after log in and redirect to a new activity?

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_page);
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvLogin);     
        setContentView(webview);            
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
                    {
        // Override URL         
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
              if(url.equals("http://Url which needs to override after login"))
              {                             
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), APImages.class);
                    startActivity(i);                         
              }                             
              return true;
        }

    });                                     
        webview.loadUrl("http://Login Page Url");

  }
```